# "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

Tags: python, error-handling

I've got a problem with my code. I want to get a referential solution for a model that shall describe the populations of bears and trouts and their interconnection.

I can't find what I did wrong, but python calls three lines with problems and end with the error 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'. What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def referenz_loesung(f, ref_loeser, x0, t0, T):
    print "Berechne Referenzloesung..."
    h_ref = 0.0001
    #it mentions the following line as problematic
    t_punkte, x_punkte = ref_loeser(f, x0, t0, T, h_ref) #it mentions this line as problematic

    print "Erstelle Funktionen aus Referenzloesungen mit Hilfe von Splines."
    a = interp1d(t_punkte, x_punkte[: , 0])
    b = interp1d(t_punkte, x_punkte[: , 1])
    return a, b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def f(x, t): # Funktion aus vorherigen Uebungen der DGL: x'(t) = f(x(t), t)
        y = np.zeros(2)
        y[0] = -2*x[0] + 10 * x[1]
        y[1] = -x[0]
        return y

    x0 = np.array([1., 0.])
    t0 = 0
    T = 10
    h = 0.5

    from unsersolver import integriere
    #it mentions the following line as problematic
    t_punkte, x_werte = integriere (f, x0, t0, T, h) 

    from implEuler import integriere as ref_loeser 
    #it mentions the following line as problematic
    x1_ref, x2_ref = referenz_loesung(f,ref_loeser, x0, t0, T)
    ref_punkte = np.linspace(t0, T, 1000)

    from woche1_1_m import auswerten_nx1
    ref_werte1 = auswerten_nx1(x1_ref, ref_punkte)
    ref_werte2 = auswerten_nx1(x2_ref, ref_punkte)
```

The things I import are from other files from earlier weeks that all work actually work properly. 
Any idea what I could do? I'm at the very start of learning python, so I don't really have a clue.
Thanks!

Comment: What't the type of `integriere`? The error told you that `integriere` is an `numpy.ndarray`, and you can't use `numpy.ndarray` with `numpy.ndarray(a,b,c,d,...)`. By the way, you should be careful of the indent in your python code as the code you post dismissed it.

Comment: It's a function (differential equation) that shall solve the process via the implicit Euler.

Comment: I'll be careful with that, sorry!

Comment: @zmwang "The error told you that `integriere` is an `numpy.ndarray`" no it didn't! "You can't use `numpy.ndarray` with `numpy.ndarray(a,b,c,d,...)`" Passing parameters to the `ndarray` class  is fine (although that's not actually what OP did; they used the `array` function instead). It's **objects** of type ndarray that cannot be called like a function.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you could post the code for integriere() or ref_loeser().
With the information I have let me ask you to try back-tracing to the root of the problem:

Start of the problem is `t_punkte, x_werte = integriere(f, x0, t0, T, h)` which you say gives a numpy error, and since the only numpy parameter you're passing to this is x0, i'd suggest checking the usage of x0 in your `integriere()` code.

Next, I'd suggest not passing a function as a parameter, I don't think that is a standard convention. You could define a `def ref_loeser(parameters..)` outside the `refrenz_loesung()` function call, and then call it like you did.

And since `referenz_loesung()` calls `ref_loeser()` which is the same as `integriere()` I highly recommend you to check the code in this function.

Good luck!

Comment: Passing function as a parameter is reasonable in certain circumstances e.g. Python's own `sort()` allows it. Numerical integration seems like one of those circumstances.

Comment: I understand. But since they are still a beginner it would be easier to start this way .. that is why I didn't say it was wrong, I just said it's not a standard convention :)

Answer (score 1):

`x_lsg =  berechne_nullstelle(x_werte(n-1))` <--- error

`x_lsg =  berechne_nullstelle(x_werte[n-1])` works?

x_werte is an ND-array, you need to access the n-1 element, use x_werte[n-1] instead.
The ( ) is for function calls, so python interpreter assumed you were calling an numpy.ndarry and hence threw that error

Answer (score 0):

You would get this error if e.g. you put `x0()` in your code. It's impossible for us to tell what the real error is without the source of the other modules.

My best guess: is it possible that you got the parameters to `integriere` in the wrong order? If so, perhaps that function tries to call the parameter, expecting it to be a function, but because you've put a numpy array in that parameter it gets "called" instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are in the right order. Guess it is difficult to post all the other things here as there are quite a lot of codes :/

Comment: @michigan2392 At least the full text of the error, including the trace back, would be useful to include. If there is too much code, try to delete as much of it as you can while still getting the error, even if the code doesn't make much sense any more. This is called a minimal example.

Comment: This is the full error code: traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MichelleHmilch/PycharmProjects/AnMaII/woche4_1.py", line 76, in <module>
    x1_ref, x2_ref = referenz_loesung(f,ref_loeser, x0, t0, T)
  File "/Users/MichelleHmilch/PycharmProjects/AnMaII/woche4_1.py", line 33, in referenz_loesung
    t_punkte, x_punkte = ref_loeser(f, x0, t0, T, h_ref)
  File "/Users/MichelleHmilch/PycharmProjects/AnMaII/implEuler.py", line 66, in integriere
    x_lsg =  berechne_nullstelle(x_werte(n-1))
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Well there's your problem: `x_werte(n-1)`. The traceback tells you exactly what the line of code with the issue was; you should have started looking there! (It's not always that easy, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the code for the implEuler file. The 'unsersolver' should be correct as it was given to me by the teacher...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from newton import berechne_nullstelle

def integriere(f, x0, t0, T, h):
    d = len(x0)
    t_punkte =  np.arange(t0, T, h)
    N =  len(t_punkte)
    x_werte =  np.zeros ((N, d))
    x_werte[0] =  x0
    for n in range(1, N):
        def f_implEuler(x):
            x_werte^(n-1) + h * f(x_werte, t_punkte^(n)) - x_werte
        x_lsg =  berechne_nullstelle(x_werte(n-1))
        x_werte[n] =  x_lsg
print integriere
```

Does that help in any way?